# Is it good practice to switch back to an old branch to develop a new feature or to create a new branch?

Tags: git, version-control

I have an old branch (`old-branch`) which I last used approximately four months ago that I used to develop a feature for a specific project.  It was never merged back into `master` because the feature never played out according to plan and was abandoned.

Since then, the project has come a very long way and the codebase now looks very different.

**Note: I have only been using git / version control for a few months now so am still learning about it.  Also, I am the only person using this repository and nobody else will ever use it, so all changes are - and will continue to be - my own.**

I now need to develop a feature for this project, and I checked out `old-branch`, but the problem was that it (naturally) reverted the original codebase (with new features) back to how it was all those months ago.

Also, when I switched back to `master`, I noticed hundreds of untracked files (from the old branch).

**My question is this: should I create a new branch (`development`/`feature`) or use `old-branch`?  If I should use `old-branch`, how should I handle the vast differences in the codebase and subsequent untracked files when I switch back to `master`?**

**Is it good practice to create and use new feature-specific branches as and when I need them?**

I would think that as a project evolves, and as new features arise, it would make more sense to branch the project off (in order to create a working copy of `master` as it is at that moment in time) so that the changes can be made, and to then merge `new-branch` back into `master` once the change is complete.  However, being a relative newcomer to git / version control, perhaps this is not the correct way to do things.  I don't know.

I was under the impression that you should have a dedicated `development`/`features` branch which you use to further develop new features, and then which you merge back into `master` once they are complete, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: Branches are basically free, so you do not have to reuse them. And once a feature branch is merged, you can delete the branch. No need to keep it around. (You can use `git branch --merged` to find branches that can be safely deleted.)

Comment: This is really good to know.

Answer (score 7):

If `old-feature` has nothing to do with `new-feature` then create a new branch.

Even if the new feature needs some code from the old feature, I would still create a new branch off the current code, and selectively checkout out files from `old-branch` into your new branch:

```
$ git checkout -b new-feature master
$ git checkout old-feature -- path/to/file/you/want
```

Git, from the command line or using a GUI, allows you to revert changes to individual lines of a file, so you can get extremely granular in what you bring over to your new branch.

Answer (score 3):

A four month old branch will be a nightmare to merge. If the feature is abandoned, delete the branch ( unless your boss is a hoarder and wants to keep it). Do not touch that old branch.

Create a new branch, do your work, merge it or don’t merge it, then delete the branch.